# Como mandar el value de un combo al controlador en Java?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, select

Tengo dos select, que se cargan al entrar a la pagina, la consulta que llena mi segundo combo **"claveSuc"**, recibe como parámetro una clave, que es la clave que yo tengo que recuperar de lo que se elija en el combo 1 **"claveAf"**, ahorita solo tengo en mi método del controller un valor en duro para que funcione, por lo cual en mi jsp tengo las siguientes funciones

** Así tengo actualmene mi jsp y al entrar a la consola del navegador cae en el "error", por que puse un console.log ahi

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  
  document.getElemnetById('claveSuc').disabled=true;
  
  
  $('#claveAf').change(function(){
   var valor = $('#claveAf').val();
   getClaveSuc(valor);
   if(valor >="1"){
    $('#claveSuc').attr('disabled', false);
   }
  });
 
 });
 
 function getClaveSuc(value){
  var dataString = "value="+ value;
  $.ajax({
   url: "/admin/registro?"+value,
   type: 'POST',
   data: dataString, 
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest){
    if(data != null){   
     console.log("exitoso");
    }
   },
   error: function(XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log("error");
   }
  });
}

</script>
<div class="form_Group">
<form:select id="claveAf" class="Select" name="claveAf" path="claveAf">
<option value="">Seleccionar</option>
<form:options items="${afor}" itemValue="clave" itemLabel="descripcion"/>
</form:select>
</div>

<div class="form_Group">
<form:select id="claveSuc" class="Select" name="claveSuc" path="claveSuc">
<option value="">Seleccionar</option>
<form:options items="${sucursales}" itemValue="clave" itemLabel="descripcion"/>
</form:select>
<input id="seleccion" name="seleccion" type="hidden">
</div>
```

al cargar la pagina mi segundo combo esta des-habilitado y hasta que se seleccione algo en el primer combo se habilita, y ya recupero el valor de la opción del combo 1 a través de un input hidden, ahora lo que quiero hacer es mandar ese valor a mi controlador, para que se lo pase como parámetro a mi consulta y cargue mi segundo combo **"claveSuc"** con la info correcta, este es mi método en mi controlador

**Asi tengo actualmente mi controlador

```html
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/registro", method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
 public ModelAndView registrar(@RequestParam(value="value",required=false) String value) {
  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("/registro", "formRegistro", new Registro());
  RespuestaServicio respuesta = new RespuestaServicio();
  try{
   model = utileria.agregarAforModel(model,utileria.obtenerComboAf(servicio.obtenerAfor()));
   if(value != null){
    model = utileria.agregarSucModel(model,utileria.obtenerComboSuc(servicio.obtenerSuc(value)));
   }
  
  }catch(Exception e){
   log.error("se presento un problema"):
  }
     model = utileria.agregarRespuesta(model, respuesta);
  return model;
 }
```

y si cambio mi metodo a como mencionas ya no me regresa nada, y no se cargan los combos, por que reciben un objeto de tipo ModelAndView, por ejemplo así esta su implementacion

```html
public ModelAndView  agregarSucModel(ModelAndView model, List<Combo> sucur){
 ModelAndView auxiliar = model;
 if(sucur != null)
  auxiliar.addObject("sucursales", sucur);
 }
 return auxiliar;
}


 public List<Combo> obtenerComboSuc(List<Sucursales> listaSuc){
 
 List<Combo> lista = new ArrayList<>();
 Combo combo;
 for(Sucursales sucursal: listaSuc){
  combo = new Combo();
  combo.setClave(sucursal.getClave());
  combo.setDescripcion(sucursal.getDescripcion());
  lista.add(combo);
 }
 return lista;
 
 }
```

entonces ya no se como lo tendría que cambiar para que lance la pagina y se carguen los combos

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas hacer la consulta a tu controller vía `ajax`, tu controller seguramente tendrá un `@RequestMapping` con el que podrás acceder a el (debería de estar al inicio del controller).

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/nombrecontroller")
```

Con este nombre podremos crear la URL del `ajax`, en el change del primer select puedes llamar a este ajax:

```
$('#claveAf').change(function(){
    var valor = $('#claveAf').val();
    getClaveSuc(valor);
    if(valor >="1"){
        $('#claveSuc').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});

function getClaveSuc(value){
    var dataString = "value="+ value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "../nombrecontroller/admin/registro", //url: "../nombrecontroller/admin/registro?value="+value,
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataString, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest){
            if(data != null){   
                //Rellenar el select
                // Voy a imaginarme que lo que le pasas será un Array de Sucursal[es]
                $("#claveSuc").html("<option value=''>Seleccionar</option>");//Vacias el select

                for(let x=0;x<data.length;x++){
                    $("#claveSuc").append("<option value='data[x].clave'>data[x].descripcion</option>");
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            //Controlar los errores
        }
    });
}
```

Por último para que funcione, en tu método del controller tendrás que 
poner `@RequestParam` y recoger aquí el valor que le pasas.

No tiene sentido que retornes un `ModelAndView` por que no quieres que se vuelva a pintar la `view` entera, por lo que yo pasaría una lista, un objeto o una lista de objetos para luego poder pintarla en el `success` del `ajax`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/registro", method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView registrar() {
    ... // Este metodo es para pintar por primera vez la view,

    return ModelAndView ;
}


@RequestMapping(value="/obtenerComboSuc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Combo>obtenerComboSuc(
    @RequestParam(value = "value", required = false) String value) {
    ... // Este metodo es para devolver el Combo, el ajax debe de llamar a este y no al que pinta la view

    return lista;
}
```

Comment: Hola, ya lo implemente y ya recupero el valor en mi controlador, ya modifique mi pregunta a como lo tengo,solo que no muestra nada en el combo, no truena nada pero no muestra las opciones que debería, una duda en la parte del Ajax del succes adentro del if que pusiste como comentario rellenar select ahí no puse nada, como debería de ser? Será que x eso no muestra nada?

Comment: Puse una condición del if, xq cuando carga la página aún no tengo nada en "value" y x lo tanto truena x null, pero después de que ya se llena ese valor ya no muestra nada en mi combo

Comment: @Root93 en la otra pregunta comentas que el ajax te cae en "error", ¿podrías actualizar esta pregunta con la información de ese error? Es importante también que cambies en tu controller el return, quitar el modelAndView por lo que comente y ademas poner `@ResponseBody delante` como puedes ver en mi respuesta, también tienes que poner el `RequestMethod.POST`, te recomiendo que pegues lo que te escribí en tu controller y que el código que tenias en el otro lo metas aquí. Actualizo la respuesta para que veas como tendrias que pintar el select en el success

Comment: ya intente cambiar el método a como mencionas, y  retornar solo la la pagina, pero no hace nada, y es que ademas si lo cambio a como dices mis combos no cargar, xq reciben un objeto model, actualizo mi pregunta para que veas a que me refiero

Comment: Creo que estas confundido en respecto a como deberías de hacerlo... Una cosa es el método del controller que sirve la view, y otra cosa es el método para devolver los datos del segundo combo. Deberían de ser 2 métodos diferentes, de modo que el de pintar la view lo dejes como lo tenias y el nuevo para pintar el controller lo dejas como el que te pongo yo en el ejemplo, son necesarias las anotaciones Spring que estas ignorando...

Comment: Ya entra al succes pero aún no rellena mi select, en la parte del for en el valor de "x", debo sustituirlo por algo?  Al igual que en el append donde esta [x]??

Comment: No entiendo cual es el problema ahora... ¿No sabes como iterar en la lista para pintar el select? En mi respuesta tienes un ejemplo, dependiendo del tipo de dato que pases tendras que iterar de una manera u otra.